# Would like to find more songs like Amy Grant's rendition of "Jesu, Joy Of Man's Desiring"

Tags: identify-this-genre, similar-artists

I adore the second part of Amy Grant's rendition of "Jesu, Joy Of Man's Desiring":
https://youtu.be/Qun3aiwcxB4?t=1m45s

I'd love to find more music like this but have no idea how to describe it. I'm not great at picking out instruments but it sounds like there are some traditional instruments (fiddles, pipes/flutes, and is that a bagpipe?!) with a full orchestra behind them.

The best I can come up with is "jig backed by an orchestra" but am hoping that you have better terms or can point me to other songs/artists in this style.

Comment: It's not an exact match, but you might enjoy the song linked in this question: https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/5715/what-does-high-cs-by-two-steps-from-hell-have-to-do-with-the-ocean --a lot of nautical soundtrack music is epic orchestral versions of Celtic hornpipes.

Comment: @ChrisSunami Thanks for the great tip! Between this and your answer, I'm listening to some amazing stuff right now. <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "jig" sound and instrumentation you are hearing are in the [*Celtic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celtic_music) music genre, which most often refers to music inspired by traditional Irish and Scottish folk tunes.

While I'm not aware of a formal "orchestral" subgenre of Celtic music, some searches that yielded similar music for me were:

["Epic celtic"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jWObTfiovD8)
["Celtic sountrack"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zmDSAXCQqyI)
["Celtic orchestra"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVb-y2J6bMA)